Way to intercept file copy-paste functions in windows using Detours to implement encryption/ decryption on files
I am not able to find the way to implement this in visual studio for development.
I want to intercept file operations like copy and paste so that i can implement file encryption and decryption.
When any copy paste operation occurs i want to encrypt that file on copy

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
